# Error when Installing dependencies on a React project (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

Hello I am currently stuck with a task that is given to me. The problem is that I am unable to install dependencies when running `npm install` which means that I am unable to run the website locally which is my main goal

There are many versions of this question in the internet but I am not really sure what the main cause of this therefore the title of this question

you can view my error logs here
https://www.codepile.net/pile/4qL4NOq0

I have also tried some solutions that I have seen on the internet such as:

1. reinstalling node
2. deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and re-npm install (this is when I have installed the node_modules but still unable to run the website locally)
3. installing grpc globally

Comment: Do you have windows or mac?

Comment: I use windows within this project

Comment: Could you share us your package.json, just to try the `npm install`? I'm sure that windows is the error.

Answer (score 0):

The version of `grpc` that you are installing (1.23.3) does not support the version of Node.js that you are using (16). You will need to use a newer version of `grpc` (the latest is 1.24.11) or an older version of Node to get that to work.

Please note that the `grpc` package has been deprecated in favor of the `@grpc/grpc-js` package. It is recommended that you use that one instead if possible.

Comment: hi  thanks for responding I have used an older of version of node, 14. but I have this error now when I try to use npm run start on my project: 
https://postimg.cc/RqZkYQ7n

Comment: Sorry, is that a screenshot of the bottom half of the error? If you want help with the `npm run` error, why focus on the output of `npm audit`? In any case, that looks like a different error from a different package, so I suggest asking a separate question about it.